# specific type before creating a copy

Tags: java

i am doing an assignment, but I am confused on one of the steps.. I am currently working on this addStudent method.

```
public void addStudent(Student studentObj){
```

the instruction says 
"If the studentObj parameter is not null, check the specific type before creating a copy."

this is the student object

```
Student student = new Student("John", "Smith", 1, "08/15/2015", 
                                  "Information Technology", null);
```

My question is how would I create a  copy. any suggestion would be really helpful. thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

`Student copy = studentObj.clone()` will create an object with "simple" fields cloned, but beware nesting and complex fields.

See this link for more info
https://dzone.com/articles/java-cloning-copy-constructor-vs-cloning

Answer (score 0):

You create a copy by simply create a new object and save the values from one object in the other object. You can provide the values in the constructor and/or with setters, depending on your class. So it looks like something like this:

```
Student newStudent = new Student(obj.getFirstName(),
                                 obj.getLastName(),
                                 obj.getWhatever(),
                                 obj.getRegistrationDate(),
                                 obj.getCourse(),
                                 obj.getWhateverAgain());
```